# A question about spin locks

Tags: spinlock

In studying the spin lock synchronization mechanism, i noticed that for each function there is also a corresponding macro, for example for spin_lock there is a function

```
static __always_inline void spin_lock(spinlock_t *lock) {
    raw_spin_lock(&lock->rlock); }
```

and the macro

```
#define spin_lock(x) pthread_mutex_lock(x)
```

Why there are two different definitions and in which circumstances it is used each one of them? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read the CPP conditions surrounding the two definitions and you'll have your answer.

Comment: @Ginnungagap that’s rather unlikely; there are no conditions surrounding the definitions, other than the usual header guards.

Comment: It sounded like that was a question that noticed two different definitions based on compiler support. Since most of the context was omitted that's what I assumed. I read your answer afterwards, my bad!

Comment: I wonder if this programming-level question would be more appropriate on SO?

Comment: @Jeff it’s a programming question, but it’s Linux-specific (*i.e.* someone knowledgeable in C but unfamiliar with the Linux kernel wouldn’t necessarily be able to answer it), so at home here as well as on SO. I don’t mind either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro is defined in [`tools/include/linux/spinlock.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13.11/source/tools/include/linux/spinlock.h#L13): it is therefore part of the `tools` tree, and only used for kernel-related tools shipped in the kernel tree. It exists so that the same primitives can be used in the kernel tree for kernel code and user-space code; the macro translates `spin_lock` into the equivalent pthreads primitive.

The inline function, defined in [`include/linux/spinlock.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13.11/source/include/linux/spinlock.h#L352), is used in the kernel itself.